# Check if java files compiled successfully in bash

Tags: bash

I wanna create some bash script like this

```
compile java files

if compilation wasn't successful
   exit

do something
```

The question is how should i check if compilations was successful

Comment: I have a feeling that this will be as simple as doing `compile java files || exit`

Comment: great, thanks. i am new in bash.

Comment: Suggestion: you'd probably be much better off using a "[Makefile](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/)" to compile ... then, if you want, check the "make" status in bash.

Answer (score 1):

Compile java ;
[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "ok" || echo " something is wrong check !"